# Python Gtk event ignore

Tags: application-development, python, gtk3, events

I would like to ignore some key events in a text view, now i do the following

```
def on_key_press_event(self,source,event):
    keyname = Gdk.keyval_name(event.keyval)
    if(keyname=="Return"):
            tv = self.builder.get_object('txtMsg')
            buf = tv.get_buffer()
            msg = buf.get_text(buf.get_start_iter(),buf.get_end_iter(),self)
            msg=msg.replace("\n","")
            buf.set_text(msg)
```

Is there any function equivalent to  Java function event.consume()  in   python?

Comment: @LordofTime Programming (development) questions are explicitly listed in the FAQ http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions as reasonable questions to ask here. If it were a general Python question, vs. how to use GTK+ in Python, I might agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop an event from propagating (unless the event has been set up using `connect_after`), you can run

```
object.emit_stop_by_name(event_name)
```

For instance, if I connected the key-press-event like this:

```
self.textview.connect("key-press-event", self.on_key_press)
```

I can stop it propagating like this:

```
def on_key_press(self, widget, event):
    self.textview.emit_stop_by_name("key-press-event")
```